# SpriteKit velocity unit and thrown

Tags: sprite-kit, game-physics

I try to design a game using SpriteKit, but I have a problem about units. According to SpriteKit guide, it uses SI units and I try to write a projectile motion code. According to [flight time equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion#Time_of_Flight), **T-Flight = 2 * V-YComp / g**

I am applying following parameters in my code:

```
V-YComp = 20 m/sec
g = 10 m/sec^2
```

According to above parameters, T-Flight must be 4 Sec.

I apply velocity to object using following line:

```
ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 20)
```

As a result of the above code, the object doesn't get thrown.

Following quote from Xcode guide:

```
The physics body’s velocity vector, measured in meters per second.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: also keep in mind that real-world physics equations often translate only very roughly to game physics, ie the resulting behavior may be more or less close to reality, but never exactly as in the real world (ie 2d physics doesn't apply drag through air resistance etc)

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a fixed velocity.

Instead, you should use apply impulse:

```
[ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 20)];
```

Also, remember to make it dynamic so physics works with your sprite:

```
ball.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I applied this method. SpriteKit guide describes the impulse as "A vector that describes how much momentum was imparted in each dimension...". p = m * v and mass of my object is 0,087 kg, hence v = 230 m/s and T-Flight must be 46s. However, T-Flight is 0,28s in the simulator. I don't understand the physics in the SpriteKit.